# listview per in click dont show Tost in kotlin lang?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

What is the wrong in `ListView` per on click dont show Tost

[image]

Comment: Please always post your code _as text_ instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you've named your parameters `p0`, `p1`, etc. If you give them their normal names, you can refer to them with those going forward:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
    // use parameter by these names
}
```